# Counterexample to a formula for the norm of a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

In my functional analysis class, I have come across this exercise

> For a Hilbert space $H$ and $A$ a self-adjoint operator on $H$ one has the familiar identity $$\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} \lvert \langle Ax,x \rangle \rvert $$
> we are asked to show a counterexample to this when $A$ is not self-adjoint.

I cannot think of any counterexample to this. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On $\mathbb R^{2}$ define $A(x,y)=(-y,x)$. Then $\|A\|=1$ and $\langle Av, v \rangle=0$ for all $v$.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take $H = \Bbb C^2$ with the standard inner product, and take $A$ to be the transformation associated with an upper triangular matrix.

Note that the set $\{x \in \Bbb C^2: \|x\| = 1\}$ can be parameterized as
$$
x(\theta, \phi, \psi) = e^{i \psi}(e^{i \phi}\cos \theta,\sin \theta).
$$
Thus, one simply needs to find the maximum $\sup_{\theta,\phi,\psi \in \Bbb R}|\langle Ax(\theta,\phi,\psi),x(\theta,\phi,\psi)\rangle|$.

---

Concretely: take
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$
Verify that $\|A\| = 1$ by finding the eigenvalues of $A^*A$. On the other hand, for $x$ in terms of $\theta, \phi, \psi$ as above, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\langle x, Ax \rangle &= \langle e^{i \psi}(e^{i \phi} \cos \theta, \sin \theta), e^{i \psi}(\sin \theta,0)\rangle
\\ & = \langle(e^{i \phi} \cos \theta, \sin \theta), (\sin \theta,0)\rangle
\\ & = e^{i \phi} \cos \theta \sin \theta = \frac 12 e^{i \phi} \sin (2 \theta).
\end{align}
$$
From there, it is clear that $|\langle x, Ax \rangle| \leq 1/2 < 1$.

Comment: thank you very much, how do I compute the operator norm of a matrix in this case?

Comment: thank you very much but this still appears complicated to me, why can I parameterized these vectors the way you did it?

Comment: @kroner Note that the validity of the other answer depends on context: if Hilbert spaces are defined to necessarily be inner-product spaces over $\Bbb C$, then $\Bbb R^2$ does not qualify and the associated operator does not work as a counterexample.

Comment: @kroner I finished writing a full answer. As for where the parameterization comes from: this is just a matter of saying that for $x = (\alpha,\beta)$, $\|x\| = |\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2$. If we write $\alpha = r_1e^{i \theta_1}$ and $\beta = r_2e^{i \theta_2}$, then we see that $\|x\| = 1$ iff $r_1^2 + r_2^2 = 1$. My parameterization comes from taking $r_1 = \cos \theta, r_2 = \sin \theta$, and the (unnecessary but perhaps convenient change) $\psi = \theta_2$ and $\theta = \theta_1 - \theta_2$

Comment: thank you very much it is fully clear now